# Can I use spring integration in stand alone application?

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to **spring integration**, and was wondering if I can use spring integration in an application that is stand alone.
The various services or workflows are communicating via channels , by posting messages. I want to control the flow of application decoratively and I find spring integration quite interesting in this regard.

Please advice.

Comment: try apache camel as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Framework is fine , I am interested if the approach can be used where the components within systems are event driven and talking to each other via messages instead of direct method invocation.I know that between 2 or more systems this approach is lot scalable and preferred.But within the system can we use the same approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; one of the design goals for Spring Integration was to enable loose coupling of components within an application where they exchange messages.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the response . Today only i was watching ur talk on Spring Integration with Spring Boot and RabbitMQ. :)